# How To Use fping Command With Subnet Format Like 255.255.255.0 In Parrot?

Tags: linux, ping, parrotsec, subnets

I'm working on a script project to detect ARP spoofing.
Firstly I need to find all my local area network neighbours. I'm using fping command to find them all.

The command im using:

`fping -a -r 0 -g 192.168.9.0/24`

But I want to use subnetmask in this command like 255.255.255.0.

How can I do it?

Comment: Could you explain why you need the mask in that form? This might help us understand your issue.

Comment: I'm trying to create a script and the subnetmask is coming from another place. Format of subnetmask is 255.255.255.0 format. Then I take this subnetmask and using in my fping command.